# Capitalisation of "Führer"

Tags: capitalization

Could you, please, say why we capitalise the not-English word "Führer", which, literally translated into English from German, means "Leader" and is, for some strange reason, used in English when referring to Hitler?

I do have a speculation on this: Maybe that's because in German, all nouns are capitalised, so it has to be capitalised in English as well?

Also, could you tell me, wise Owls, that strange reason why English people began using "Führer" instead of "leader" when referring to Helter?

Example:

1. The **F**ührer has just said he shall not surrender!

Comment: When *Führer* means *Hitler*, it's a proper noun, and should be capitalized. (We often say *"the President*, *the Prime Minister*, *the Premier*).

Comment: Do you mean "Helter" or is that a typo?

Comment: Nothing strange is happening here: titles referring to particular people are often capitalised in English, as are nicknames and other terms. Whether it's the King (referring to the present King Charles III), the Russian Foreign Minister (Sergei Lavrov), il Duce (Mussolini), the Great Emancipator (Lincoln), the Iron Lady (Thatcher) or many others.

Comment: @Anton, I think it's a minced oath.

Answer (score 2):

In German, common nouns are generally capitalized, but German words are typically *not* capitalized when incorporated into English sentences, even when italicized (see [Capitalization of German words in English sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46563/capitalization-of-german-words-in-english-sentences)). In this case, however, *Führer* is a job title, much like *President.*  Style guides differ as to when exactly job titles should be capitalized (see [APA](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/apa/other/capitalization), [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Biography#)), but in at least some cases you would indeed capitalize *fürher* when using it in English.

Comment: The answers to the cited question do not all agree 'German words are typically *not* capitalized when incorporated into English sentences'; some of them convincingly argue that the matter depends on whether the word is perceived as a German word in an English sentence, or has effectively become an English word (which is the same rule as usually governs the italicisation of foreign words). It is true, however, that with respect to this particular word, the matter is preempted by its being a title of sorts, as is the case with, say, [*Kaiser*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40131).

Comment: @jsw9: it wasn't a title "of sorts". Hitler's [official title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler) was "Führer und Reichskanzler".